# unable to add comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I have gone to a couple of questions now to add a comment and get an error has occurred message.
Obviously I can still ask questions.
I also was able to edit a question.
anyone else have this problem? 
Or is it a browser setting again?
I see other comments on the same questions.
it must be a browser block of some kind.

[image]

Comment: what is the error? can you comment on this question?

Comment: let's see if the comments work in meta. ??

Comment: just on GIS SE?? not sure what it is.

Comment: Looks like GIS SE only

Comment: Potential Internet Browser or Connection? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46474/dont-blow-away-comment-box-until-success-is-assured

Comment: More likely IT control with watchguard. It happens every time on GIS SE but never on meta

Comment: seems you can [add comments again](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81066/arcgis-10-2-installation-for-64-bit-geoprocessing/81069#comment113604_81069)

Comment: un-explainable.